# Is there any disadvantage regarding memory in multiple variable declaration in PIG LATIN?

Tags: variables, apache-pig

I've read many discussions regarding PIG and I noticed that every line needs to declare a variable.

Is there any drawbacks if you're going to declare new variable?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'declare new variable'? Can you give a code example?

Comment: `A = LOAD data USING PigStrorage();    
B = FILTER A;    
C = GROUP A BY $1;`  
Question: Is there any memory allocation for each variables (A, B and C)? Which will slows down the data processing of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Each line is a processing step and you need to put the results somewhere to use it in subsequent steps. So I'm not sure how you would proceed without the variable at the beginning of the line. Since you probably knew that I think you are asking if you need to choose a new variable name for each line of if you somehow save resources by re-using an existing name. This is explictly adressed in the "Programming PIG" book by Alan Gates (O'Reilly), so I will simply quote the  relevant paragraphs:

> Pig Latin is a dataflow language. Each processing step results in a
>   new data set, or relation. In input = load 'data', input is the name
>   of the relation that results from loading the data set data. A
>   relation name is referred to as an alias. Relation names look like
>   variables, but they are not. Once made, an assignment is permanent. It
>   is possible to reuse relation names; for example, this is legitimate:

```
A = load 'NYSE_dividends' (exchange, symbol, date, dividends); 
A = filter A by dividends > 0; 
A = foreach A generate UPPER(symbol);
```

> However, **it is not recommended**. It looks here as if you are
>   reassigning A, but really you are creating new relations called A,
>   losing track of the old relations called A. Pig is smart enough to
>   keep up, but it still is not a good practice. It leads to confusion
>   when trying to read your programs (which A am I referring to?) and
>   when reading error messages.

Comment: Come to think of it I haven't actually answered your question - the quote has just established that one should not overwrite relations for reasons unrelated to memory.  I have frankly no idea if overwriting relations frees any memory as opposed to keeping relations ( I would assume that at some point garbage collection kicks in, but I'm not at all an expert in these things). So now I'm curious what the answer is, too :-)